# WPF-MVVM: Binding between UserControl from different project

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a project solution as below

[solution with different project in MVVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBkO6.png)

The Start Window is ***MainWindowStart.xaml*** located in *ProjectStart.View* with Datacontext *ProjectStartViewModel.cs*.

***MainWindowStart.xaml*** includes 2 UserControls (**MyUC1.xaml, MyUC2.xaml**) that are located in a different project (*Project1*) with DataContext ***Project1ViewModel.cs***
[as showen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqaHq.png). The properties are correctly binded on  InitializeComponent() of MainWindow but not working when the property change. 
It works fine when the user controls are included in a window that is located in a some project of user control

This is the code of Property in a ViewModel ViewModel

```
 private int _IndexTabMain;

    public int IndexTabMain
    {
        get { return _IndexTabMain; }
        set
        {
            if (_IndexTabMain != value)
            {
                _IndexTabMain = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IndexTabMain");
            }

        }
    }
```

and this is the code of property binded in  **MyUC2.xaml** that is notified from a selection change in **MyUC1.xaml**

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.IndexTabMain, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

In advance thank you
Manuel

Comment: As a general rule, you should never explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl. Doing so effectively prevents that a DataContext is inherited from the parent control or window, which usually breaks your Bindings. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28982771/1136211

Comment: Where is the IndexTabMain property defined?

Comment: Your UserControl should expose DependencyProperties on their surface to which you bind your ViewModel.  Just like a TextBox has a Text property, your user control should have a Whatever property that is bound to your view model's Whatever property.

Answer (score 0):

If `IndexTabMain` is defined in the view model of the parent window, you should set the `AncestorType` property to `Window`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.IndexTabMain, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
```